# Rails 3 ActiveRecord query question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model `X` that `belongs_to :y` and has a field `quantity`

The `Y` model:

```
has_many :xs
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :z
```

The `User` model:

```
has_many :ys
has_many :xs, :through => :ys
```

The `Z` model

```
has_many :ys
has_many :users, :through => :ys
```

How can I find how many `xs` a user has for a particular `z`?
How can I find the sum the quantity fields for the `xs` that a user has for a particular `z`?

I would like to find a solution that uses rails 3's active record query syntax and takes place at the database level as much as possible please. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: x, y and z aren't helpful names. Please use real values instead of fake ones. We will not steal your ideas. It also allows us to speak in your terms.

Comment: __User__ `has_many :zs, :through => :ys` ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to translate this in another fashion.

The X model becomes a Cart Item

```
class CartItem
  belongs_to :cart
  attr_accessor :quantity
end
```

The Y model becomes a Cart

```
class Cart
  has_many :cart_items
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :section
end
```

The User model stays the same

```
class User
  has_many :carts
  has_many :cart_items, :through => :carts
end
```

The Z model becomes a Section

```
class Section
  has_many :carts
  has_many :users, :through => :carts
end
```

Therefore, you asked:

- How can I find how many cart items a user has for a particular section?
- How can I find the sum the quantity fields for the cart items that a user has for a
  particular section?

Add the following scope to CartItem

```
scope :for_section, lambda { |section|
  includes(:cart).where('carts.section_id = ?', section.id)
}
```

And the answers will be

- user.cart_items.for_section(section).count
- user.cart_items.for_section(section).sum('quantity')

These commands will generate the exact SQL query to find the answers you're looking for!